# Visual Studio Reporting an error with a push_back() function call on a vector of structs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, casting, directx-11

So in the program there is a struct that looks something like this:

```
struct VERTEX 
{
    FLOAT X, Y, Z; 
    D3DXVECTOR3 Normal;
};
```

And in the program header file there is a storage container (a vector) to store vertex structs:

```
std::vector<VERTEX> cubeVerts;
```

And within the program there is a function to populate the vector of structs with structs:

```
cubeVerts.push_back({-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)});    // side 1
cubeVerts.push_back({1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)});
cubeVerts.push_back({-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)});
cubeVerts.push_back({1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)});
```

However visual studio is reporting errors, highlighting the first curley bracket of each call of the push_back() function with a red underline and reporting when highlighted: Error: expected an expression. I was just wondering if the reason that the reason the error was being reported is because I was not typecasting the data to a VERTEX struct or if typecasting to a D3DXVECTOR3 in the function call was somehow illegal?

Comment: What version of  VS do you use?

Comment: The C++11 support in VS 2010 is far from complete (the "10" in "2010" provides somewhat of a hint about that) and I believe that initializer lists is one of the missing features. (And there is no typecasting your code.)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow - its in the tag - visual-studio-2010, although I don't believe this has anything to do with the reason why the push_back() commands are not valid because as far as I'm aware the syntax is correct.

Comment: @molbdnilo there is no mention in the question of C++ 11 and isn't placing D3DXVECTOR3 in front of (0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) typecasting?

Comment: The program is utilising the old DirectX sdk installed seperately, OS is Windows 7 rather than 8.1 - in the new DirectX sdk D3DXVECTOR3s are deprecated I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio C++ 2010 does not support usage of initializer lists as arguments of constructors of standard containers. You should use a more modern Visual Studio release.

Comment: Funny because when I type the following: D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) the program compiles - this is the same thing right without using the list as an argument - just typecast 3 variables to the vector.

Comment: @Enchanter It seems that class D3DXVECTOR3 has a constructor with three parameters.

Comment: Ye sorry - took a while to comprehend what you were getting at before. I suppose then that if I really want to use VS 2010 - the values will have to be loaded in manually to a temporary VERTEX struct before being pushed back into the vector?